# B2 visa for US - ESTA instead?

Tags: visas

I'm a British citizen with a US spouse and dual national daughter. My husband is required to work in the US for a year and although we applied for a B2 visa for me to join my family out there, I can't get an interview at the Embassy in London until Mar 22! We need to leave in July. Has anyone tried to go to the US on an ESTA and then fly out and back in again after 90 days? Were you successful? I don't know how else to accompany my family out there when I can't even get an appointment for a visa interview!

Comment: Have you misstyped the month? ('Mar 22')

Comment: You could try going on ESTA and then going to Bermuda for your visa.  It's an idea that has a number of potential problems but at least the appointment wait time in Hamilton is currently 28 days: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html

Comment: @MarkJohnson the next March after today falls in the year 2022, so I don't think there is an error there.

Comment: Yeah the US Embassy in London is somewhat notoriously just not functional right now when it comes to non-immigrant visas. I doubt it's a typo.

Comment: Is even a B2 visa appropriate to live in the US for a full year?

Comment: @jcaron yes. The regulations allow an initial admission of up to one year, indefinitely extensible by increments of up to six months.  The B-2 is the appropriate visa for family members accompanying someone in a status that does not have a derivative status associated with it, or for a family member whose relationship does not qualify for the derivative status.  See 9 FAM 402.2-4(B)(5): "This is also an appropriate classification for applicants who are members of the household of a U.S. citizen who normally lives and works overseas but is returning to the United States for a temporary period."

Comment: @jcaron https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040202.html